# Formatting columns in peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I use Postgres, python3 and peewee.
In the query below I have two column results that would help me a lot.

select hrreference::time(0), to_char(hrreference, 'HH24:MI:SS.US') from wshop.documen

How do I get any of these columns using peewee commands?

hrreference is my table field and it has data with and without the milliseconds.

Comment: what does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: There is a lot going on.
I can list a few:
1 - Database data (Postgres, SQL Server, xls, csv....)
2 - Formats have to do with Pandas (Text, date, time....).
2 - Dictionaries lists also have to do with pandas.
. . .

Now what? Can you help me?

Comment: see the guide to [tagging](/help/tagging) and the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info) tag wiki. Only use tags for questions which directly relate to the tag. pandas is a specific python package. You should not include a tag just because the subject matter vaguely overlaps. Your question appears to be about how to query a postgres database using the peewee package. If this does have something to do with pandas, please be explicit about how you need help regarding pandas code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should give you the idea:

```
Document.select(
    Document.hrreference.cast('time(0)'),
    fn.to_char(Document.hrreference, 'HH24:MI:SS.US'))
```

To answer your question from above, I ran the following code and found that Peewee already successfully converts the `time` from Postgres into a python standard-lib `datetime.time`:

```
# Populate a subset of your sample data - we can insert
# these as strings, they will be converted properly.
class Document(db.Model):
    hrreference = TimeField(null=True)

db.drop_tables([Document])
db.create_tables([Document])

data = {
    "51856": "11:01:26.473000",
    "135705": "10:45:13.068000",
    "178439": "14:11:27.043000",
    "235084": "14:11:22.315000",
    "242198": "14:08:32.749000",
    "199531": "11:35:01.355000",
    "185596": "11:33:00",
}
for t in data.values():
    Document.create(hrreference=t)
```

Now when we query the data back, it comes to us as a `datetime.time`:

```
query = Document.select(Document.hrreference).dicts()
pprint.pprint(list(query))
```

Output:

```
[{'hrreference': datetime.time(11, 1, 26, 473000)},
 {'hrreference': datetime.time(10, 45, 13, 68000)},
 {'hrreference': datetime.time(14, 11, 27, 43000)},
 {'hrreference': datetime.time(14, 11, 22, 315000)},
 {'hrreference': datetime.time(14, 8, 32, 749000)},
 {'hrreference': datetime.time(11, 35, 1, 355000)},
 {'hrreference': datetime.time(11, 33)}]
```

I hope this answers your question and provides the data in a workable format for you.

Comment: It gets results but converts everyone to the same schedule.

Comment: Can you provide info on the underlying data and data-types of the `hrreference` column, in that case?

Comment: I have added a reply below merely to make the text more formatted.